# React native Share.share not working for sharing text

Tags: react-native, sharing

Following this tutorial, I found this error. I'm not sure if it is my wrong doing, or if it is an error in the code.

It appears Share.share does not work. I can not find anything online regarding this function.

## Error Message

[image]

## Share.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'



class Share extends Component  {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._shareMessage = this._shareMessage.bind(this);
    this._showResult = this._showResult.bind(this);
    this.state = {result: 'Hello'};
  }

  _showResult(result){
    this.setState({result})
  }

  _shareMessage() {
    Share.share({
      message: 'This is a fancy shared message'
  }).then(this._showResult);
}

  render(){  
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress = {this._shareMessage}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Share</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}
      </Text>
    </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#10a2f0',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'rgb(0,10,200)',
    marginTop: 100,
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  image: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250
  }
})

export default Share
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to import Share class as well:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight, Share } from 'react-native'
```

Also, you should change your class name to something else (like ShareExample)

Try to stick to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/js/ShareExample.js) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create alias of the import like

```
import {Share as ShareText} from 'react-native';
```

then

need to update the method

```
_shareMessage() {
    ShareText.share({
      message: 'This is a fancy shared message'
  }).then(this._showResult);
}
```